# Binding in XAML not working, if variable changed in code (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm quite new to coding in C# and XAML and I just can't get the binding to work in XAML. It works once, when I initialise the presenter class, but doesn't update the Textbox Text, if I change the bound variable in the code afterwards.

When the program starts, "200" is displayed in the Textbox. If I press the Button, all the Messageboxes are displayed (showing "100"), but the Textbox still shows "200" instead of "100".

I tried many solutions I found online, but none seemed worked.

The Presenter Class (ViewModel):

```
class Presenter : ObservableObject
{        
    float _xText;

    public float xText
    {
        get { return _xText; }
        set
        {
            _xText = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("xText");
        }
    }        

    public ICommand Update
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(_Update); } 
    }

    public Presenter()
    {
        _xText = 200f;
    }

    void _Update()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("_Update");
        _xText = 100f;
        //Debug
        MessageBox.Show(_xText.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(xText.ToString());
    }
}
```

The XAML Code (View):

```
 <TextBox IsReadOnly="False" 
          IsEnabled="True" 
          Text="{Binding Path=xText, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
 <Button Command="{Binding Update}"/>
```

The ObservableObject class:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }  
    }
}
```

I hope someone has a solution or can explain where I went wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: As an extra comment: properties (public) follow PascalCase, fields (private) follow camelCase or underscoreCamelCase. Follow this and you won't have these problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are updating the backing field not the property so NotifyPropertyChanged is not getting called.  Try the property instead

```
void _Update()
{
    MessageBox.Show("_Update");
    xText = 100f;
    //Debug
    MessageBox.Show(_xText.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(xText.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Indeed it is fundamentally important to never access the backing field especially in Class Code. That is why you should append a underscore to it in the first place - so you do not mix them up by accident.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I don't know why I could not see it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem:

1. You are setting the backing variable _xText so it isn't running the property xText. (As @Ken-Tucker said)

(EXTRA CHANGES)

2. I never use float in C# or in the (SQL Server) database. (You will regret it.)

See [here](http://jacobmsaylor.com/the-difference-between-decimal-double-and-float-examples-in-c/) "the difference between decimal, double and float".

3. See if you can replace:

   ```
   RaisePropertyChangedEvent("xText");
   ```

   with

   ```
   RaisePropertyChanged(() => xText);
   ```

You will avoid a lot of cases of getting stung with typoes.

4. You have a property named xText?  Hope it is just for the question, otherwise not good. You are writing for the reader. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members) with naming guidelines.

Comment: 1. I changed it. It works fine. Thanks.
2. Ok, I'll get rid of the floats.
3. Unfortunatly it does not work. 
4. It was just for the example, but I think I have to work on my naming.
Thanks